# Downloading loaded webpage as html

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm new here. My problem is I got a loaded tab on chrome and the webpage is not accessible anymore.
anyway, the page contents are still on the server at least thumbnails.
Is there a way to download this tab entirely with its page structure as HTML for viewing later. 
I don't turned off my pc for 2 days only hibernate it. Searching for a way but can't find any resource.

edit: the webpage is a meganz folder which has ~100 folders on it. i think it's very hard to download with page structure because it loads a file explorer application (server-side i think) when first loading the folder and files.

Comment: Your question seems to be unclear. Is this a programming issue? What do "download this tab entirely with its page structure", "I got a loaded tab on chrome and the webpage is not accessible anymore", etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Either File > Save Page As.. (in Chrome)

or

2. FTP into the web server and download the whole folder/page from the public_html folder, if it is a static page. If it's not, you'll only get template files, and no content data.

or if you're just interested in reading the content:

3. File > Print > Save as PDF

Comment: I tried the save page as but it not work for me. 

The webpage is a meganz folder i don't think it will allow me to do that.

Pdf will work but i need to repeat the same thing for ~100 folders if there is a way to download as html it will be much faster and easy

Comment: @Bohembyte Weird that you can't save the page. Did you select Webpage, Complete once you clicked Save Page As ... ? How did it not work, did you get any error messages? Are you on Linux or some other operating system?

Comment: yeah i select complete and when i open the html it tries to load server-side(im not sure if it is) file explorer application and error pop up appears. Mega failed to load because..  the file "lang/tr_****long text and numbers******.json" could not be loaded.

Comment: @Bohembyte Aha, that must be the files that are missing from the web now, that makes the page impossible to reload as you described in your initial post. If the .json language file isn't available, the whole translation system fails and the page won't show any text. So I guess this is a lost case if you can't get hold of the missing files. You can check which files are missing by right clicking on the page > Inspect > Console.